# Band values based on values in another dataframe in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a table of data like the following, with many columns:

**MAIN DATA**

| ID | STATUS | BALANCE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100005 | Live | £246.00 |
| 134305 | Live | £552.00 |
| 193933 | Live | £49,456.00 |
| 193895 | Live | £5,671.00 |
| 129031 | Closed | £0.00 |

Each column has rows in a lookup table. I would like to band the columns in the main table into strings and return their corresponding number based on the values in the lookup table:

**LOOKUP TABLE**

| Variable | Band | Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| STATUS | Live | 5 |
| STATUS | Closed | 8 |
| BALANCE | (-0.01, 500] | 11 |
| BALANCE | (500, 1000] | 22 |
| BALANCE | (1000, 2000] | 56 |
| BALANCE | (2000, 100000] | -55 |

I want values that exceed either available boundary to be placed in the appropriate bucket, e.g. if I had a balance of -9999, it should be placed in (-0.01, 500].

The result should be like this, where for the numeric fields I also return the band name as a string.

**OUTPUT**

| ID | STATUS | BALANCE | BALANCE_Band | STATUS_Num | BALANCE_Num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100005 | Live | £246.00 | (-0.01, 500] | 5 | 11 |
| 134305 | Live | £552.00 | (500, 1000] | 5 | 22 |
| 193933 | Live | £49,456.00 | (2000, 100000] | 5 | -55 |
| 193895 | Live | £5,671.00 | (2000, 100000] | 5 | -55 |
| 129031 | Closed | £0.00 | (-0.01, 500] | 8 | 11 |

I understand that for the string fields I can just do `pd.merge()`, but how do I categorise the numeric fields dynamically based off another dataframe?

Comment: Why don't you simply use `pandas.cut?

Comment: I think you can use `pd.cut()` indeed. Take all the bins from the `lookup table`, use them to create a new column in the `main_data` table using `pd.cut(main_data['balance'], bins=interval_from_lookup_table)`. Finally use `pd.merge()` to merge the dataframes using the newly created column as one of the merge keys.

Comment: I'm almost there, but I'm having merge issues after the `pd.cut()`. The resulting column has dtype  `Category` and won't merge back onto my Lookup Table to bring back the number. I've also tried converting the `Category` to `str` by using `.astype('str')` and that still doesn't work... any ideas?